# How to control the way windows are opened by "next-error" and "previous-error"?

Tags: window-splitting, grep

## The context

In the gif shown below, I demostrate that the way `next-error` show the current error in a new window depends on the size of the font.

- When using the font `Fira Code 20`, a single window is used to show the selected error.
- When using the font `Fira Code 10`, 3 windows are used to show the selected error.
- When using the font `Misc Fixed:pixelsize=7`, 7 windows are used to show the selected error.

[image]

## The question

How can I change the behavior of `next-error` and `previous-error` so that a single window is opened on the right of the compilation buffer (i.e. the `*grep*` buffer) and make this behavior not to be affected by the size of the font being used?

Comment: See the relevant section of `compilation-goto-locus`; i.e., `(if from-compilation-buffer (let ((pop-up-windows t)) (pop-to-buffer (marker-buffer mk) 'other-window)) (switch-to-buffer (marker-buffer mk)))` [comments from code omitted].  I have other projects on my plate at the moment, so perhaps another forum participant can write up an answer ...

Comment: Now that I have a little more free time this evening, I am at a complete loss regarding how a user could achieve the results depicted in the GIF animation by using a default installation of Emacs -- i.e., without any user-configuration and/or additional third-party libraries.  Are you able to reproduce the issue with a barbones installation with no user-configuration; aka `emacs -Q`?

Comment: The Emacs I show in the gif was opened by executing `emacs -Q` . As seen in the gif, I only use commands which are bundled with Emacs, namely, `grep`, `set-frame-font`, `next-error`. To achieve the results, execute `grep` on a set of files so that `next-error` have multiple files to open and make sure you have a big and a small font. You can create ten files containing only numbers (as seen in the gif) by executing the following one-liner `for i in $(seq 1 10); do seq 1 100 > $i.txt; done` just make sure to execute that command in an empty folder so that you could remove those files easily.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that the function responsible of telling whether a window should be splitted or not is `window-splittable-p` (in v28.2). You can see how this function is called by instrumenting `window-splittable-p` with Edebug (press `C-u M-x` in the function definition) and then calling `edebug-pop-to-backtrace` (by default, bound to `d`) while in debug mode.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Make Emacs use the small font
2. Split the windows as you want `*grep*` to split when showing results. In the GIF you showed, when using the big font, there are two windows of the same size that are vertically arranged
3. Use `(window-height (selected-window))` and `(window-width (selected-window))` to get the height and width of any of the windows (both have the same size, so you can choose either of them)
4. Define the following mappings in `grep-mode-map`. Here, we set `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold` to values that are greater than the values reported by the previous sexp. Thus, `window-splittable-p` will always evaluate to false which will result in no splits.

```
(defun my/next-error-no-select ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((split-height-threshold 140)
        (split-width-threshold 260))
    (next-error-no-select)))

(defun my/previous-error-no-select ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((split-height-threshold 140)
        (split-width-threshold 260))
    (previous-error-no-select)))

(define-key grep-mode-map (kbd "n") 'my/next-error-no-select)
(define-key grep-mode-map (kbd "p") 'my/previous-error-no-select)
```